# How do I stop my advisors from suggesting to offer mercenaries contracts?

Tags: distant-worlds-shadows

In the Distant World expansions shadows it is now possible to offer a contract to pirates to attach a certain target of another empire. My advisers are regularly suggesting to offer such a contract, but I would rather not get their advice anymore. How can I turn it off?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Empire Policy screen (fourth icon on the top bar, looks like a notepad). Go down to "War & Attacks," then change "Offer Pirate Attack Missions" to "Never."

[image: Relevant section of the policy dialog]